# Django RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField error in my django python model

Tags: python, django

I have created in models a class with a DateTimeField whcih I believe is causing an error in my project

```
class Job(models.Model):
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number_of_bids = models.IntegerField()
    time_starting = models.DateTimeField()
    time_ending = models.DateTimeField()
```

The error returned is as below

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Job.time_ending received a naive datetime (2018-10-25 10:03:58.889072) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

Any tips on fixing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a Python's datetime value into your models.

i.e this one

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now() # Incompatible with Python's DateTimeField directly
```

What you need to be doing is pass a time-zone aware object from the `from django.utils import timezone` like this

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.now() # Will fit right into DateTimeField in your model
```

*Quoting from the docs* : 
*Naive and aware datetime objects*
Python’s `datetime.datetime` objects have a `tzinfo` attribute that can be used to store time zone information, represented as an instance of a subclass of datetime.tzinfo. When this attribute is set and describes an offset, a datetime object is aware. Otherwise, it’s naive.

You can use `is_aware()` and `is_naive()` to determine whether datetimes are aware or naive.

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Answer (score 0):

The datetime you are passing is not Timezone Aware. you will have to add timezone to the datetime field.

If using python/django to save timezone:

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.now()
```

If you are serializing data then instead of `'2018-10-25 10:03:58.889072'` use `'2018-09-09T00:00:00Z'`